# How add div in right top position in td?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need refact this task [How to add triangle in table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499048/how-to-add-triangle-in-table-cell)

I need not background a div.

```
    <td>
     <div style="position: relative;right: 0;top:0;">@Html.ImageContent("triangle_bonus.png", "")</div>
//@Html.DropDownListExtention
    </td>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the second image you posted what the code is currently doing and you want it to be achieved as indicated by the first image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
<td style="position: relative;">
<div style="position: absolute;right: 0;top:0;">@Html.ImageContent("triangle_bonus.png", "")</div>
</td>
```

---

How about changing your html to:

```
<td class="triangle">
<div>@Html.ImageContent("triangle_bonus.png", "")</div>
</td>
```

And adding this to the head of you html:

```
<style>
td.triangle {position:relative}
td.triangle div {position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
</style>
```

Look at this for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Juvcx/

Comment: but I can not use relative in td. but td have any element violate their work