# How to add triangle to input[type='text']

Tags: html, css

I want to add a small triangle to the upper-right corner of an `input type='text'` HTML element, like Excel uses to indicate a comment.

The accepted answer to this question:

[How to add triangle in table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499048/how-to-add-triangle-in-table-cell)

shows how to do it for a table cell.  I naively applied the "note" css class to my input element but it didn't work.  Any suggestions for how to achieve this?

Comment: Pls post ur code.

Comment: 3 downvotes; it would be helpful to add a comment to say what's wrong with the question.  I thought it was clear enough what I want from the answer to the linked question without posting code.

Comment: Upvoted. Both the question and the answer are useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pseudo elements [can't be used on `input`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/746736). You can use the same CSS as described in the linked post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14499545/746736)) but you would have to apply the class to an ancestor.

```css
.note {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.note:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    display: block;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Given a simple input field

```
 <input type="text" />
```

and assuming we can't use or rely on a parent element for styling, you may use multiple `box-shadow` to create a triangle, e.g.

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryoYVv)

---

**Result (triangle outside)**

[image]

---

**Code**

```
input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 -12px 0 #fff, 12px 0px 0 #fff, 
              1px -12px 0 #fff, 2px -11px 0 #fff, 
              3px -10px 0 #fff, 4px -9px 0 #fff, 
              5px -8px 0 #fff, 6px -7px 0 #fff, 
              7px -6px 0 #fff, 8px -5px 0 #fff, 
              9px -3px 0 #fff, 10px -2px 0 #fff, 
              11px -1px 0 #fff, 12px 0 0 #fff, 
              8px -12px 0 #9bc;
}
```

Of course you can change the size of the triangle playing with the offset(y/x) of the box-shadow.

If you need to place the triangle inside the input you could just add a couple of properties to the code above and use `outline` and `outline-offset` instead of the `border` property to create the *illusion* of an outer border. All the shadows don't move from their position, just give enough space to the offset in order to wrap them.

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpEJXX?editors=1100)

---

**Result (triangle inside)**

[image]

---

**Code**

```
input {
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   outline: 1px #ccc solid;
   outline-offset: 15px;  
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's great +1. Only thing with this is that I guess the triangle has to be outside of the element. I'm not sure if this is what OP wants or not. great solution though.

Comment: Impressive answer.

Comment: to build on this answer... one could set the input to no border and wrap it in a div with a border, giving the triangle an appearance of being in the element.

Comment: @Turnip I've just included the inner triangle version. it's easier than using a parent element :)

Answer (score 0):

To mark all text inputs with red corner, you could use

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input:not([type]) {
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, red 5px, white 5px);
}
```

If you want to mark only required fields, then use `required` attribute and selector:

```css
[required] { background: linear-gradient(225deg, red 5px, white 5px); }
```

```html
<input placeholder="optional field">
<input placeholder="mandatory field" required>
```